# Mysql: insert, delete and update in single statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a case where I need to insert or update multiple entries in a table corresponding to a key.
What I'm currently doing is, delete all entries from the table corresponding the key and inserting them all. In case of a table with delete-marker, an update statement is executed to mark all as deleted and new entries are inserted/updated there after.

The case is as shown below, thanks to [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/sql-insert-delete-and-update-in-one-statement-sync-your-tables-with-merge-14814215d32c)
[image]

The difference in my situation is, source is not a different table.

for example, for the table `PizzaDay`, the schedule dynamically changes. So when a reschedule happens, new entries needs to be inserted/updated, and non-pizza days needs to be deleted/marked-deleted (adding a new delete marker is also okay).

```
CREATE TABLE PizzaDay (
    `Id` int
    , `CreatedOn` datetime(3) NOT NULL
    , `ModifiedOn` datetime(3) NOT NULL
    , `StartDate` datetime(3) NOT NULL
    , `EndDate` datetime(3) NOT NULL
    , PRIMARY KEY (`Id`, `StartDate`, `EndDate`)
);
```

Any idea how to achieve this in single statement?

Comment: It's not possible. You can do `INSERT/UPDATE` with `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`. But there's nothing that combines with `DELETE`.

Comment: Also, don't conflate "single statement" with "atomic". In RDBMS where it is supported (e.g. SQL Server) `MERGE`  is not atomic. You should use a transaction.

Comment: in that case which one is efficient, mark existing as deleted and insert/update, or delete existing and insert all new? I guess "mark existing as deleted and insert/update" as more efficient since there is no deletions involved, right?